# Error al cargar codigo html mediante .html()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un problema al momento de hacer la carga de una tabla mediante el metodo `javascript .html()` el cual detallo a continuación:

la siguiente función es ejecutada cuando deseo mostrar un registro a editar el cual contiene una cabecera y detalles del registro

```js
//*** FUNCION PARA MOSTRAR FORMULARIO DE EDICION DE FICHAS ***//
function mostrar(idficha)
{
 //*** MEDIANTE EL METODO POST CAPTURAR TODOS LOS DATOS DEL FORMULARIO ***//
 $.post("../ajax/ficha.php?op=mostrar", {idficha: idficha}, function(data, status)
 {
  //*** CONVERTIR TODOS LOS DATOS CAPTURADOS EN OBJETOS A SER MANEJADOS POR JS ***//
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  mostrarform(true);
  //*** MEDIANTE JQUERY BUSCAR EL OBJETO CON EL ID idficha Y ASIGNARLO AL ***//
  //*** DOM HTML EN EL INDICE idficha ***//
  $("#idficha").val(data.idficha);
  clearInterval(window.intervalo);
  $("#c").html(data.cod_ficha);
  $("#codficha").attr("value",data.cod_ficha);//
  $("#mes_pre").val(data.mes_pre);
  $("#mes_pre").selectpicker('refresh');
  $("#fecha_hora").val(data.Fecha);
  $("#idinstitucion").val(data.idinstitucion);
  $("#idinstitucion").selectpicker('refresh');
  //*** CAPTURAR EL ID DE LA INSTITUCION DE LA FICHA A MOSTRAR ***//
  $("#idinstitucion option:selected").each(function () {
   //*** ALMACENAR EL ID DE LA INSTITUCION EN UNA VARIABLE ***//
   idinstitucion = $(this).val();
      //*** ALMACENAR EL ID DE LA ACTIVIDAD EN UNA VARIABLE ***//
      r = data.idactividades;
      //*** CARGAR EN EL SELECT idactividades LAS ACTIVIDADES DISPONIBLES ***//
      $.post("../ajax/ficha.php?op=selectActividad", { idinstitucion: idinstitucion }, function(data){
       $("#idactividades").html(data);
       //*** SELECCIONAR LA ACTIVIDAD DE LA FICHA A MOSTRAR ***//
       $('select[name=idactividades] option[value='+r+']').attr('selected','selected');
       $("#idactividades").selectpicker('refresh');
      });            
     });

  $("#objetivo").val(data.objetivo);
  $("#resumen").val(data.resumen);
  $("#idequipo").val(data.idequipo);
  $("#idequipo").selectpicker('refresh');
  //*** CAPTURAR EL ID DEL EQUIPO DE LA FICHA A MOSTRAR ***//
  $("#idequipo option:selected").each(function () {
   //*** ALMACENAR EL ID DEL EQUIPO EN UNA VARIABLE ***//
   idequipo = $(this).val();
         //*** ALMACENAR EL ID DEL RESPONSABLE EN UNA VARIABLE ***//
         s = data.idresponsable;
         //*** CARGAR EN EL SELECT idresponsable A LOS RESPONSABLES DISPONIBLES ***//
         $.post("../ajax/ficha.php?op=selectResponsable", { idequipo: idequipo }, function(data){
             $("#idresponsable").html(data);
             //*** SELECCIONAR EL RESPONSABLE DE LA FICHA A MOSTRAR ***//
             $('select[name=idresponsable] option[value='+s+']').attr('selected','selected');
             $('#idresponsable').selectpicker('refresh');
         });            
     });

  $("#idambito").val(data.idambito);
  $("#idambito").selectpicker('refresh');
  //*** CAPTURAR EL ID DEL EQUIPO DE LA FICHA A MOSTRAR ***//
  $("#idambito option:selected").each(function () {
   //*** ALMACENAR EL ID DEL EQUIPO EN UNA VARIABLE ***//
   idambito = $(this).val();
         //*** ALMACENAR EL ID DEL RESPONSABLE EN UNA VARIABLE ***//
         t = data.idprovincia;
         //*** CARGAR EN EL SELECT idresponsable A LOS RESPONSABLES DISPONIBLES ***//
         $.post("../ajax/ficha.php?op=selectProvincia", { idambito: idambito }, function(data){
             $("#idprovincia").html(data);
             //*** SELECCIONAR EL RESPONSABLE DE LA FICHA A MOSTRAR ***//
             $('select[name=idprovincia] option[value='+t+']').attr('selected','selected');
             $("#idprovincia").selectpicker('refresh');
         });            
     });
  $("#rf").val(data.idprovincia);
  //*** CAPTURAR EL ID DEL EQUIPO DE LA FICHA A MOSTRAR ***//
  //*** ALMACENAR EL ID DEL EQUIPO EN UNA VARIABLE ***//
  idprovincia = data.idprovincia;
     //*** ALMACENAR EL ID DEL RESPONSABLE EN UNA VARIABLE ***//
     u = data.iddistrito;
     //*** CARGAR EN EL SELECT idresponsable A LOS RESPONSABLES DISPONIBLES ***//
     $.post("../ajax/ficha.php?op=selectDistrito", { idprovincia: idprovincia }, function(data){
         $("#iddistrito").html(data);
         //*** SELECCIONAR EL RESPONSABLE DE LA FICHA A MOSTRAR ***//
         $('select[name=iddistrito] option[value='+u+']').attr('selected','selected');
         $("#iddistrito").selectpicker('refresh');
     });            
     $("#centro_poblado").val(data.centro_poblado);
     $("#dificultades").val(data.dificultades);
     $("#reflexiones").val(data.reflexiones);
     $("#acuerdos").val(data.acuerdos);
     $("#adjuntos").val(data.adjuntos);
  //*** Ocultar y mostrar los botones ***//
  $("#btnGuardar").hide();
  $("#btnCancelar").show();
  $("#btnAgregarPrd").hide();
 });
 //*** Mediante el metodo post listar los detalles de la ficha a mostrar ***//
  $.post("../ajax/ficha.php?op=listarDetalle&id="+idficha,function(r){
         $("#detalles").html(r);
 }); 
}
```

los detalles(**la tabla en mención**) del registro son cargados mediante el metodo `$.post` el cual trae la información de:

```html
//*** 15. CASE QUE LISTARA LOS DETALLAS DE LA FICHA A MOSTRAR ***//
  case 'listarDetalle':
   //*** Recibimos el idficha ***//
   $id=$_GET['id'];

   $rspta = $ficha->listarDetalle($id);
   $total=0;
   //*** Codigo para mostrar la cabecera de la tabla ***//
   
         //*** Por cada detalle se tiene que mostrar una fila mediante un bucle ***//
   while ($reg = $rspta->fetch_object())
     {
      echo '<tr class="filas"><td></td><td>'.$reg->nombre.'</td><td>'.$reg->varones.'</td><td>'.$reg->mujeres.'</td><td>'.$reg->total.'</td><td>'.$reg->descripcion.'</td></tr>';
     }
   echo '<tfoot>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                    </tfoot>';
   break;
```

el problema es que cuando ejecuto la función `mostrar()`, no siempre carga la tabla que es llamada con el `case 'listarDetalle'`. Es decir, a veces carga correctamente la tabla mediante el `.html(r)` y a veces simplemente la tabla no es cargada dentro de `(#detalles)`

Comment: ¿Revisaste si te da algún error en la consola?

Comment: Si, ningún error. Como menciono el error es aleatorio, osea a veces la tabla si es cargada con los datos correctamente y otras veces simplemente no se carga nada en (#detalles)

Comment: Dices que el error es aleatorio, ¿para un mismo `id`? Es decir, ¿el error lo da sin importar el `id` enviado en la consulta? O te has dado cuenta si lo hace siempre con un `id` en particular?

Comment: Así es, mediante consola verifique que el id enviado es siempre el correcto. Es un error en el DOM creo, es como si la memoria del navegador no reconoce ese fragmento de codigo html enviado.